# Visual Studio 2008 Window layout annoyance

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having a weird issue with Visual Studio 2008. Every time I fire it up, the solution explorer is about an inch wide. It's like it can't remember it's layout settings.

Every un-docked window is in the position I place it. But if I dock a window, it's position is saved, but it's size will be reset to very-narrow (around an inch) when I load.

I've never come across this before and it's pretty annoying. Any ideas?

The things I've tried:

- Saving, then reloading settings via Import/Export.
- Resetting all environment settings via Import/Export.
- Window -> Reset Window layout.
- Comination of rebooting after changing the above.
- Installed SP1. No improvement

none of which changed the behaviour of docked windows. (Also, definitely no other instances running..)

I do run two monitors, but I've had this setup on three different workstations and this is the first time I've come across it.

Comment: Can you please change the accepted answer to Eric Minkes's answer? I don't understand why you Accepted a workaround instead of the real solution. I just had this problem and Eric Minkes's solution was right on.

Comment: Eric's solution wasn't related to the issue I was having. I was definitely maximising my window, yet still had the weird docked window size issue.

Comment: Eric's solution as stated was pretty terse. To flesh it out: First you need to unmaximise (Restore) your window, resize it to be big, and then maximise it again. Did you try that?

Comment: Yeah, I did. However upgrading our projects to VS2010 solved any weirdness. Tbh, it could have been the weird corporate environment. I'm just happy people have found Eric's answer so good. Also, didn't realise I could change the accepted answer. Thought that was a one-time deal. Turns out it's not. Thanks Deadcode! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem. It turned out that if the VS window was non-maximized, it was really
small. So after making the non-maximized wider, the problem disappeared.

Comment: Eric you are a life saver. I'd vote this up a thousand times if I could. I had tried everythign (except un-maximizing the window) and once I saw your comment the behavior I was seeing made total sense. Needless to say, I had a very difficult time coming up with the right search phrase to look for help.

Comment: Don't think I ever would have figured that out!

Answer (score 3):

I occasionally get this bug, and others related to layout/fonts/colouring etc. A little trick I've found is use the Tools -> Import and Export Settings, export your current settings once you've got everything setup as you like, then close and reopen Visual Studio and import. Hopefully that'll sort you out.

In 2005 there were some little bugs with viewing Project/Solution property panels when the Solution Explorer wasn't in its default position, docked on the left of the screen - I don't know if that's changed in VS2008, but you might want to put it back there and see.

Now, when are we going to get decent MultiMonitor support?!

Comment: Multi monitor support comes in Visual Studio 2010 which features a WPF rewrite of the IDE.  THe windows will be tear off windows which can be dragged onto a second monitor.  Details at: http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2009/02/20/a-new-look-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're closing Visual Studio while some other instance is still alive. The settings of the last instance that is closed is the one that will be applied.